# Inconsistent answers from inferring probability of success from probability of failure

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Alright so I was working on my previous post and stumbled into a problem. Say the $P(A$) failing is $0.02$, which translates to $2\%$ failure rate.
Say the P(B) failing is 0.003, which translates to $0.3\%$ failure rate.
Assuming the event of $A\cap B$ is mutually inclusive and independent, then $P=A\cdot B$ in terms of probability of failure.
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)
\\
0.02\cdot 0.003
\implies 6\times10^{-4}\implies P=0.00006 \ \text{or} \ 0.006\% \ \text{chance of failure }$$

Now, in terms of success I should be able to say $P(A)=2\%$ implies a success rate of $98\%$. Likewise, $P(B)=0.3\%$ implies a success rate of $99.7\%$. 
When I do the same exact operations in terms of success now, I get
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B) \\
0.98\cdot 0.997\implies P=0.97706 \ \text{or} \ 97.706\% \ \text{chance of success}$$

It doesn't matter what A and B represent, my issue is why the numbers don't match up. I should be able to say that, if $x$ = 100% and $y$=probability of failure, then $x-y$ = probability of success. A $2\%$ failure right literally implies a $98\%$ success rate and a $0.3\%$ failure rate literally implies a $97.706\%$ success rate! But thats not happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You compute the probability of *both* $A$ and $B$ failing versus the probability of *both* $A$ and $B$ succeeding. You ignore the cases when one of $A,B$ fails and the other succeeds.

Comment: Ah, so how do I account for when one or the other fails or both fails?

Comment: You have to decide whether A failing and B succeeding is success or failure.  In either case, the probability of this is figured the same way, as $0.02\cdot 0.997$

Comment: $${\hspace{4.25ex}\mathsf P(A\cap B)~+~\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)~+~\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B)~+~\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\\=(0.02\cdot 0.03)+(0.02\cdot0.97)+(0.98\cdot0.03)+(0.98\cdot 097)\\=1}$$